# Iterate over items in one column while referencing a tag in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I'm managing many stock brokerage account, each account have different types of stock in it. I'm trying to write some code to perform a stress test.

What I'm trying to do is, I have 2 dataframes:

Account information (dataframe):

```
account = {'account':['1', '1', '1', '2', '2'], 'Stock type':['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'], 'share value' = '100', '150', '200', '175', '85']}
```

stress test scenario(dataframe):

```
test = {'stock type':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'stress shock':['0.8', '0.7', '0.75', 0.6']}
```

Given these 2 dataframes, I want to calculate for each account, what's the share value after the stress shock.

i.e. for account #1, after shock value = 100*0.8 + 150*0.8 + 200*0.7 = 340

I tried some basic for loop, but my jupyter notebook will soon crush (out of memory) after the run.

```py
shocked = []
for i in range(len(account)):
    for j in range(len(test)):
        if account.loc[i,'Stock type'] == test.loc[j,'stock type']:
            shocked.append(account.loc[i,'share value']*test.loc[j, 'stock type']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can first do a `merge` to get the data of the two dataframes together. Then we calculate the `after shock value` and finally get the `sum` of each `account`:

```
merge = account.merge(test, on='Stock type')

merge['after_stress_shock'] = pd.to_numeric(merge['share value']) * pd.to_numeric(merge['stress shock'])

merge.groupby('account')['after_stress_shock'].sum()

account
1    340.00
2    186.25
Name: after_stress_shock, dtype: float64
```

**Note** I used [`pandas.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) since your values are in `string` type.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I realize there's lots of errors in the question I constructed, it makes more sense to have my values in float, sorry for the inconvenience. I didn't know you can merge dataframe with different dimensions. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Series` to [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) "stock type" to "stress shock".

Then use [`pandas.groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with a `lambda` function for desired result:

```
stress_map = test.set_index('stock type')['stress shock']

account.groupby('account').apply(lambda x: (x['Stock type'].map(stress_map) * x['share value']).sum())
```

[output]

```
account
1    340.00
2    186.25
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, Chris. This is very useful info!

Comment: @idkanythingaboutcoding no problem buddy, happy to help :)